# Structural Pattern Matching on Types

Tags: python, types, pattern-matching

I would like to apply Structural Pattern Matching https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/ on things like `list[ int ]` and `dict[ str, any ]`.
However when I try:

```py
T = list[ int ]

match T:
    case list[ t ]:
        print( t )
    case dict[ str, t ]:
        print( t )
    case _:
        print( ":)" )
```

I get `SyntaxError: expected ':'`, Which I don't find to surprising as the pattern matching seems to only work using Constructors and not the `[]` operator however when looking at the documentation for types, I found

```py
>>> list[int] == GenericAlias(list, (int,))
True
```

So I tried

```
from types import GenericAlias

T = list[ int ]

match T:
    case GenericAlias( t_origin=list, t_args=(t,) ):
        print( t )
    case GenericAlias( t_origin=dict, t_args=(str,t) ):
        print( t )
    case _:
        print( ":)" )
```

But then I get `:)`

How can this be fixed?